# Gas estimation error when creating an nft auction

Tags: solidity, contract-development

[edit] this is the error. it happens when calling the create auction function as described below.

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted
```

Been trying to create an nft auction and succeeded in simpler prototype but am having trouble actually creating the auction for my actual use case.. As the title says **the problem** is gas estimation error and atm it's on the Create Auction function, both pasted below or here found in [gist](https://gist.github.com/iFrogHop2Worlds/d078d7b34b8d9366334e1f1346cf407a#file-contracts-auctionimplement-sol)
and base implmentation here [or scroll up from first link (gist)](https://gist.github.com/iFrogHop2Worlds/d078d7b34b8d9366334e1f1346cf407a#file-contracts-auctionbase-sol)

```
function createAuction(
        ERC1155 _nftAddress,
        uint256 _tokenId,
        address _seller,
        uint128 _startPrice,
        uint256 _duration,
        uint128 _highestBid,
        address _highestBidder
    )public payable
    {
        require(_ownerOf(address(_nftAddress),_tokenId));
        _escrow(msg.sender,address(_nftAddress), _tokenId);
        Auction memory auction = Auction(
            ERC1155(_nftAddress),
            uint256(_tokenId),
            payable(_seller),
            uint128(_startPrice),
            uint64(_duration),
            uint128(_highestBid),
            payable(_highestBidder)
        );
```

Comment: Hi, can you add the error you're getting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: added the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was foolishly grabbing the nft address I guess inappropriately. When I changed some of the ERC1155 declarations as simply address and referenced the address to set the erc1155 ref obj using the nft address arg I was already providing in the function it worked.